# Как запустить Selenium с профилем Chromium?

Tags: python, selenium, chromium

Вопрос прост, а решение.. Акцентирую внимание на том, что браузер Chromium. Не Chrome!
Код выглядит так:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/home/max/.config/chromium')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile_name')
webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=Service(driver_path))
```

Во всех подобных вопросах пишут, что это все решение проблемы,но браузер запускается с профилем, ловит ошибку и падает. Ошибка такова:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Я посмотрел параметры запуска.
***БЕЗ** добавления профиля* их много:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --disable-features=TFLiteLanguageDetectionEnabled --enable-pinch --allow-pre-commit-input --data: --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-blink-features=ShadowDOMV0 --enable-logging --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.3typJJ --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end data:,
```

*С **добавленным** профилем их 6 штук*:

```
/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --disable-features=TFLiteLanguageDetectionEnabled --enable-pinch --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --desktop-startup-id=lxpanel-997-ubuntu-chromium-browser-1_TIME305114
```

Я попробовал добавить все недостающие параметры к вебдрайверу с профилем, но они не добавляются. Их как было 6 так и осталось! Как можно вылечить этот вопрос?

Answer (score 0):

ваши настройки вроде работают, хромиум не валится.

Версия 111.0.5563.64 (openSUSE Build), stable (64 бит)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import sqlite3
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import UnexpectedAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


import logging
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

options.add_argument('user-data-dir=/home/ru/.config/chromium')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile_name')

browser = webdriver.Chrome(#executable_path='/home/ru/webdriver/chromedriver'
                           options=options
                           , service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=chromiumdriver.log"]
                           , service=Service('/home/ru/webdriver/chromedriver')
)


browser.get('https://service.nalog.ru/inn.do')
timeout = 5
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, timeout)
browser.find_element(By.ID, 'unichk_0').click()
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'btn-next').click()
time.sleep(7)
```

хмм, из любопытного, для просмотра версии хромиума оставил хромиум запущенным и запустил программку еще раз. это оно?

```
 /bin/python3 /home/ru/py.1/p1/so234.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ru/py.1/p1/so234.py", line 25, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(#executable_path='/home/ru/webdriver/chromedriver'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 104, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 286, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 378, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 440, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55d7d8a3d243 <unknown>
#1 0x55d7d88017a6 <unknown>
#2 0x55d7d882a520 <unknown>
#3 0x55d7d882649b <unknown>
#4 0x55d7d88682a7 <unknown>
#5 0x55d7d88678cf <unknown>
#6 0x55d7d885ee53 <unknown>
#7 0x55d7d88319ea <unknown>
#8 0x55d7d8832b2e <unknown>
#9 0x55d7d8a91d5e <unknown>
#10 0x55d7d8a95a80 <unknown>
#11 0x55d7d8a778b0 <unknown>
#12 0x55d7d8a96b63 <unknown>
#13 0x55d7d8a68f75 <unknown>
#14 0x55d7d8ab9998 <unknown>
#15 0x55d7d8ab9b27 <unknown>
#16 0x55d7d8ad4c23 <unknown>
#17 0x7f950e273615 start_thread
```

Comment: Хмм.. мне бы стоило добавить версию. Версия 111.0.5563.64 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (32 бит) Но я не понял что вы спрашиваете? Если ошибка, то да - такая де. Я читал в некоторых местах, что надо закрыть свой браузер, чтобы зайти под профилем с селениумом. Я запускал и с открытым браузером и без - результат один.

Comment: на это и обращаю внимание, что у меня ошибка не возникала при отсутствии другого запущенного хромиума. вероятен баг, исправления которого ждать неопределённое время.